# How can I delete doubled words in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to delete doubled words from string in Perl, for example i have a string : 
This is text text text very important and and meaningful simply simply text.

And i do this:

```
$linia =~ s/(.*)\1/$1/g;
```

But it only works for two doubled words, how to change to make it for 2+ doubled words.

Comment: Note that when you say "it only works" that is not quite true. It doesn't work at all, if you count how many times it will match when it should not. Such as with repetitions inside words, `pool` -> `pol`. Language parsing is always a complex task, and if you want to use simple tools like this, you need to be very strict about applying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `+` to match on or more times,

```
$linia =~ s/(.*)\1+/$1/g;
```

or if you want to remove all duplicates,

```
my %seen;
$linia =~ s|(\w+)| $seen{$1}++ ? "" : $1 |ge;
```

Comment: Tried out. Worked. But leaves multiple spaces between words.

Comment: @Matthias do you want to remove all duplicates, or only consecutive ones?

Comment: only consecutive, it deletes also text from the end.

Comment: Note that `s/(.*)\1+/$1/g` also deletes repetitions inside words, so that `pool` -> `pol` and `barbarian` -> `barian`.

Comment: @mpapec This is a non-trivial problem, language is complex.

Comment: I believe it is trivial for @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @mpapec I don't know who that is.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $str = q/abcabcabcabc/;
$str =~  s/(.+?)\1+/$1/;
print $str,"\n";
```

If you have spaces between words:

```
my $str = q/abc abc abc abc/;
$str =~ s/(\w+\s+)\1+/$1/g;
```

**Output:**

```
abc
```

Comment: @Matthias: You haven't said you have spaces between words.

Comment: I don't think you have actually tried that second substitution on a real text.

Comment: @TLP: What do you mean? In what cases doesn't it work?

Comment: @M42 Any case.. your last comment becomes `you mean? cases doesn'it work?` for example.